# How to restrict implicit conversion of typedef'ed types?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Suppose there're two types:

```
typedef unsigned short Altitude;
typedef double Time;
```

To detect some errors like passing time argument in position of altitude to functions at compile time I'd like to prohibit implicit conversion from `Altitude` to `Time` and vice-versa.

What I tried first was declaring an `operator Altitude(Time)` without an implementation, but the compiler said that it must be a member function, so I understood that it's not going to work for a `typedef`ed type.

Next I've tried turning one of these types into a class, but it appeared that the project extensively uses lots of arithmetic including implicit conversions to `double`, `int`, `bool` etc., as well as passes them to and from streams via `operator<<` and `operator>>`. So despite this way allowed me to find the errors I was looking for, I didn't even try to make full implementation of the compatible class because it would take a lot of code.

So my question is: is there a more elegant way to prevent implicit conversions between two particular `typedef`ed types, and if yes, then how?

Comment: The `typedefs` have nothing to do with it. They are not new types. They are aliases for existing types.

Comment: Why `Time`? There's already `std::chrono::duration`

Comment: @MSalters because it fitted its purpose better (there's lots of arithmetic with it), and because project started when C++11 didn't yet exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `typedef` does nothing more than establish another name for an existing type.

Therefore your question boils down to whether you can disable implicit conversions between `unsigned short` and `double`, which is not possible in general.

Two ways exist to deal with this problem:

First, you can make `Altitude` and `Time` into their own types (read: define `class`es instead of `typedef`s) and ensure that they can be easily converted to and from their underlying numeric types - but not each other.

Second, you can ensure that whatever you do is protected by language constructs, e.g. if you have a function `f` that should take an `Altitude` a.k.a. `unsigned short`, you can overload it with another function `f` that takes an `Time` a.k.a. `double` and causes an error. This provides a better overload match and would thus prevent the implicit conversion in that case.

Comment: The overloaded function that causes an error is a good idea, but it only catches errors at run time. I'm not a C++ expert, but isn't there a way to detect such errors at compile time?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Overload resolution very much is a compile time check. It's part of the static type safety mechanism. Only `dynamic_cast` is a RTTI check.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, but the suggestion, as I understand it, is to provide two overloaded functions, one for `unsigned short` that does the right thing, and one for `double` that "causes an error". I'm thinking something like `void func(unsigned short arg){do_the_right_thing;}` `void func(double arg){abort();}`. Is there a way to cause a call like `func(42.0)` to be a compile-time error?

Comment: @Keith: `void func(double arg) = delete`

Comment: @MSalters: As of C++11, you can do `void func(double arg) = delete;`. For earlier versions of C, I think you can just declare it but never define it, which produces a link-time error (though in that case the error message likely won't give you a line number).